# Making parallel jquery ajax call trigger only last call's callback method

Tags: jquery, ajax

These are the two calls-

```
var url = '/Home/ListData?ipaddress=' + ipaddress;
processAjaxRequest(url , 'Post', 'fetchDataComplete', DataModel);

processAjaxRequest('/Home/ListException', 'Post', 'fetchExceptionComplete',DataModel);

function processAjaxRequest(urlToProcess, httpMethod, successCallback, postData) {

    $.ajax({
        url: urlToProcess,
        type: httpMethod,
        data: dataToPost,
        success: function (data, status) {
            var fn = window[successCallback];
            fn(data);
        },
        error: function (xhr, desc, err) {
            processAjaxError(xhr, desc, err);
        },
    });
}

function fetchDataComplete(data) {

    //some stuff

}

function fetchExceptionComplete(data) {

    //some stuff

}
```

If I change the sequence of ajax call, It is going on the call back method of last function executed.I want both gets executed.

Comment: i am not sure what exactly you want but you can use [jQuery promises](http://api.jquery.com/promise/)

Comment: looks fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/spTjW/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can either use promises or you can just keep track of when the second ajax call completes like this:

```
var url = '/Home/ListData?ipaddress=' + ipaddress;
// set state for how many ajax calls we're waiting for
var callsRemaining = 2;
processAjaxRequest(url , 'Post', 'fetchDataComplete', DataModel);
processAjaxRequest('/Home/ListException', 'Post', 'fetchExceptionComplete',DataModel);

function processAjaxRequest(urlToProcess, httpMethod, successCallback, postData) {
    $.ajax({
        url: urlToProcess,
        type: httpMethod,
        data: dataToPost,
        success: function (data, status) {
            --callsRemaining;
            if (callsRemaining <= 0) {
                 var fn = window[successCallback];
                 fn(data);
            } else {
                 // perhaps store the data from the first ajax call that completed
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, desc, err) {
            processAjaxError(xhr, desc, err);
        },
    });
}
```